# inner DIV locked to lower right hand corner of outer DIV

Tags: css

Given the following HTML

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green; float: right; vertical-align: bottom;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the inner div to lock into the lower right hand corner of the outer div.  What do I need to do CSS wise to make that happen?

Thanks!
John

Comment: If this helps someone, Using this SO question, posted a descriptive answer in somewhat similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793879/how-to-set-a-divs-position-inside-another-div-to-bottom-right-corner/44024570#44024570

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`position` is your friend

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0px;width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Give that a try. Short version: position:relative on the outer div, position:absolute on the inner div and tell it you want the inner div to be 0 pixels from the right and bottom edges of the parent container.

Comment: just wanted you to know someone is still benefitting. Unless you work with this stuff every day tidbits like this are needed. And I needed the reminder that the parent div needed to be relative. Thank you.