# Putting content in opposite corners of table cell

Tags: css

I have a table that represents a monthly calendar.  In each cell, I want the date to appear as a number in the top left.  In the bottom right, I want a button that has a "+" to allow a user to add content to that day.  I have this working when the cells are all the same height, but it breaks down when content stretches the height of a row to different sizes.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLVh6/

Sample table layout:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>Content goes here</div>
        <div><input type="button" value="+" /></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>Content goes here</div>
        <div><input type="button" value="+" /></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>Content goes here</div>
        <div><input type="button" value="+" /></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>Content goes here.  The problem starts when there's a lot of content and the row gets stretched, the button should be in the bottom right in the other cell.</div>
        <div><input type="button" value="+" /></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

And sample CSS for where I've gotten so far:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 300px;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

td div:first-of-type {
    font-size:large;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}

td div:not(:first-of-type) {
    clear:left;
}

td div:last-of-type {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "How do I align an element to the bottom right of a table cell?"

Comment: Yes, but there were also some extra spacing elements I'm going for.  Between the three of these, though, I'm definitely happy with the result I've got on my end now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
td{
    position:relative;
}
input{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Though you'll need to give your buttons a class otherwise you'll affect all inputs.

And this won't cause the text to flow around it...

Answer (score 1):

[Position is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421100/inner-div-locked-to-lower-right-hand-corner-of-outer-div):

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 300px;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
}

td div:first-of-type {
    font-size:large;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

td div:not(:first-of-type) {
}

td div:last-of-type {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Note the changes to remove the floating and add position.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it absolutely to the bottom right of the container. You'll need to make the parent container relative so that absolute works correctly.

```
td div:last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Check out this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FLVh6/1/