# How to set a div's position inside another div to bottom right corner?

Tags: html, css

[In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/8np2f/2/):

*html*

```
<div style="width:50%;overflow:hidden">  
        <div id="inboxHeader">
                    <div id="inboxCount"><p>Earth</p></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

*css*

```
#inboxHeader{
        background-color:yellow;    
        height :300px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #inboxCount{
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 0;
        float:right; 
    }
```

`Earth` is in the `bottom left` corner. So how can I shift it to the `bottom right` corner?

Comment: To know about the positioning check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `right:0` instead of `float:right`

http://jsfiddle.net/8np2f/4/

Answer (score 1):

As it's an absolutely positioned element change `float:right;` for `right: 0px;`

If it was positioned relatively then you would need to `float` it to the `right` however absolute positioning removes the element from the flow of the DOM.

One caveat however, make sure the parent element has it's position set either to `relative` or `absolute` as required, or the child element could position itself against the highest in the DOM tree that has a position set.

Answer (score 1):

`float`-ing has no effect on `absolute`-ly positioned elements. Set the `right` attribute instead.

So, change this:

```
#inboxCount{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    float:right; 
}
```

To this:

```
#inboxCount{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

`<div style="width:50%;overflow:hidden">
    <div id="inboxHeader">
        <div id="inboxCount">
            <p>Earth</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

CSS

```
#inboxHeader {
    background-color:yellow;
    height :300px;
    position: relative;
}
#inboxCount {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; /* No need for float:right with absolute positioning */
}
```

I've update your [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8np2f/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the rule right: 0 in the id inboxCount.

Here's an example: http://zip.net/brmZth

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a descriptive answer so it might help someone.

**position property can be used to tackle this problem**

```
<div id="outer" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid red; position: relative">
    <div id="inner" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid yellow;  right:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle to check a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8np2f/102/)

If we set relative positioning on 'outer' div, any elements within 'outer' div will be positioned relative to 'outer' div. Then if we set absolute positioning on 'inner' div, we can move it to the bottom right of 'outer' div using 'right' and 'bottom' properties.

**Relative** : 
If you specify position:relative, then you can use top or bottom, and left or right to move the element relative to where it would normally occur in the document.

What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set position: relative; on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position: static; But if you DO give it some other positioning attribute, say, top: 10px;, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it would NORMALLY be.

**Absolute** : When you specify position:absolute, the element is removed from the document and placed exactly where you tell it to go. And a type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it.

***Any element that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block.***

References :

- http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/
- https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/